# Coordinates of imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an imageview (lets say imageview) and green square imageview(greenimageView) and both are added on a self.view.

Assumption: greenimageView never moves.
On scroll, imageview  moves and I need to find out the coordinates of greenimageView on imageView(overlaping region)

[image]

In my example below it would be nose and eyes area.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Lol! You're choosing x and y as the names of different views and wanting to know the Cartesian coordinates of them. Ie the x and y values for x and y. How about calling them greenSquare and imageView. Or something like that.

Comment: @Fogmeister thanks for pointing out this.I renamed it.Thanks.

Comment: @SergeyNikitin : i want to know the coordinates of green shaded region of imageview in posted image (in above example it would be image eye and nose area). Assumption: Image can move anywhere but green box is always at centre.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `convertRect:toView` method:

```
CGRect rect = [self.view convertRect:y.frame toView:x];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply convert the box position to `UIIImageView` coordinates.

```
CGPoint greenPosAccordingToImageView = [self.imageView convertPoint:self.greenBox.frame.origin fromView:self.greenBox.superView];
```